# Iterate through a list of dictionaries to sum value with the same key

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

Please be nice; I'm a newb.

I'm trying to sum the values across multiple dictionaries inside the same list, all with the same key (record_amount). This seems like it should be fairly simple, but I can't iterate over floats. How can I get around this?

```
examplelist = []

def append_data():
 examplelist.append({
  'record_number':len(examplelist)+1,
  'record_amount':float(input('Amount: '))
  })

append_data()

for data in examplelist:
 print(sum(data['record_amount']))
```

This results in 'float' object not iterable. I tried changing  the initial input to a str input instead of a float input but that didn't seem to help.

I've also tried approaches that are similar:

```
def net_income_func():
  cheers = examplelist[0:]['record_amount']
  for data in cheers:
    print(data)
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction, that would be great. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program needs a bit of adjustment for it to make sense:

```
def append_data(examplelist):
 examplelist.append({
  'record_number':len(examplelist)+1,
  'record_amount':float(input('Amount: '))
  })

examplelist = []
append_data(examplelist)

print(sum([data['record_amount'] for data in examplelist]))
```

I have changed `append_data()` to take `examplelist` as a parameter rather than it be global.

You can use a list comprehension to extract the values and `sum()` will sum all of those.